# Programmatically Getting Total Time and Busy Time of Function on Linux

Tags: c, linux, function, time, profiling

Is there any way to programmatically get the total time that a C program has been running, as well as the amount of that time spent inside a particular function? I need to do this in the code since I want to use these two values as arguments for another function. Since I am on Linux, would I be able to use gprof or perf to do this?

Comment: Have you done any research? There are `times` and `clock` functions, among others.

Comment: Also, see http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/profiling/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Grab the system time when the program starts. Then, whenever you want, you can get the current time and subtract the start time. That tells how long you've been running, in wall-clock time.
2. Have a global boolean Q that is set True when your function is entered, and False when it exits, so it is only True while the program is "in" the function (inclusively).
3. Setup a timer interrupt to go off every N ms, and have two global counters, A and B. (N does not have to be small.) When the timer interrupts, have it increment B regardless, but only increment A if Q is true.

This way, you know how much time has elapsed, and A/B is the fraction of that time your function was on the stack.

BTW: If the function is recursive, let Q be an integer "depth counter". Otherwise, no change.

Comment: Alternatively, can't I just start a new timer inside the function every time it is called, and when the function returns, add that elapsed time to a counter (like B in your example)?

Comment: @John: That would work but, calling the get-time routine could be expensive compared to what goes on in your function. The advantage of the interrupt method is the sampling rate can be as low as you want. It doesn't have to be high frequency.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [`gprof`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/gprof/), but that requires *re-compiling* the binary you want to measure to insert the required monitoring code. By default, programs don't spend time recording this data, so you must add it. With gcc, this is done using the [`-pg`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g_t_0040command_007bgprof_007d-580) option.

Comment: How would you get the profiling data programmatically from gprof? I don't see a way.

Comment: -pg inserts code to count function calls and keep tracker of the caller; it doesn't insert monitoring code; monitoring is done by the OS, which periodically samples the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof.html#SEC4) for the same.